# Calling Speech API in iOS Safari from callback

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari, text-to-speech

I want to use the HTML5 Speech API to synthesize speech by calling `window.speechSynthesis.speak(...)`, which works in nearly all browsers as expected, but I have some trouble with iOS Safari:

Calling `speechSynthesis.speak(...)` is only possible in iOS Safari if the user has actually triggered the function call himself by clicking somewhere. If this is the case, everything works as expected. The problem I have is that I need to call `speechSynthesis.speak(...)` in a callback function that is called when a http request returns. As this callback function is no longer directly triggered by the user, the speech synthesizer doesn't work.

Is there any way to work around this restriction? I know that the behavior is supposed to protect the user from misuse of the API, but in my scenario the synthesis **is** triggered by a user action, but there's the remote request in between.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33748459/226844 I don't know if what this guy suggests work or not, will try it when I get my hand on an iPhone. Maybe u can try it and let me know

Comment: https://responsivevoice.org/faq/#thb-section-0-row-0-column-0-block-5 also according to this, user action is only needed the first time

Comment: You're right, you only need to trigger it from a user action once. So, what I've done is that I call speechSynthesis.speak(" ") when the user does something. Later calls of speak(...) work then, regardless of what triggered them!

Comment: Fantastic!  I'm going to do the same for my site http://readaloud.news