# Are there requirements in the iPhone (iOS 13) settings for HTML5 Speech Synthesis to work?

Tags: html, ios, text-to-speech

I've already searched and found a couple of questions about speech synthesis issues on iOS.

Like this one:

[JS Speech Synthesis Issue on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193704/js-speech-synthesis-issue-on-ios)

I have implemented all the work-arounds I could find and I don't have any error in the console. Still I get no sound while it works fine on Android and desktop. Even the codepen shared in the question above doesn't work but the author claims it should.

So, this question is more about the device / OS itself: is there anything in an iOS device such as the iPhone, that could prevent text to speech to work? (yes, I checked the volume)

My iOS version is 13.4.1

For completeness sake, my code looks like this:

```js
let hasEnabledVoice = false

/**
 * Bug in some browser that dont load voices
 */
if (window.speechSynthesis) {
  // Preload voices
  speechSynthesis.getVoices()

  /**
   * iOS hack
   * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193704/js-speech-synthesis-issue-on-ios/62587365#62587365
   */
  document.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (hasEnabledVoice) {
      return
    }
    const fakeUtterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello')
    fakeUtterance.volume = 0
    speechSynthesis.speak(fakeUtterance)
    hasEnabledVoice = true
  })
}

function speak(sentence) {
  if (window.speechSynthesis) {
    const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(sentence)
    utterance.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices()[0]
    utterance.volume = 1
    utterance.rate = 0.9
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance)
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call speak()?

Comment: It's a react app, the user can select words to make a sentence. There is a "play" button which ends up calling the speak function.

Comment: Try adding speechSynthesis.cancel() before const utterance = ....

Comment: Also try commenting out the volume and rate lines. I doubt the 'bug in some browser' code does anything good so comment that out too.

Comment: I have updated ios to 14.4.2 and I got sound. Still interested if someone has an explanation for ios 13.